# send enter key on python Paramiko ssh

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to create a function that connects to a machine from another machine via minicom. After connecting to minicom enter should be pressed in order to send commands to the machine connected by minicom. My python code is as follows:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(self.serialHost, username=self.username, password=self.password)
shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
shell.send('minicom free -o')
shell.send('\u000d')
ssh.close()
```

Can someone tell me how can I send the enter key correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when trying to execute commands in paramiko you don't have to invoke a shell and can just call `ssh.exec_command(...)`.  If the command you want to execute depends on the environment that starting a shell would give you, then you have to explicitly call the `invoke_shell()` method.

When you use `invoke_shell()` in paramiko, you'll have to send the line termination character(s) that the particular shell expects.  If the machine you're ssh'ing to has `bash` as it's default shell, you have to send a newline (i.e. `'\n'`) character after each command.  For example:

```
shell.send('ls\n')
```

instead of

```
shell.send('ls')
```

If you're connecting to an older Windows machine, you need to send both a carriage return and a newline (i.e. `'\r\n'`) for the command to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `'\r\n'` for the return key, but I think there is also an `exec_command` method call that would not require for the return key. Something like.

```
shell.exec_command('minicom free -o')
```

[source](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.exec_command)